# “addItem” in Portal for ArcGIS not working?

Tags: python, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to upload a PDF file to my content in Portal for ArcGIS using python. So far, I'm able to succesfully create a token, but I'm having troubles using REST operation :  Add Item/Add ItemMultipart/Add Part. Here's my code:

```
def get_token(username, password):
  """ Returns an authentication token for use in ArcGIS Online."""
  portalUrl = 'some_portal_url'
  token_url = 'some_portal_url/sharing/rest/generateToken?'

  # Set the username and password parameters before
  #  getting the token. 
  params = {'username' : username,
            'password' : password,
            'client' : 'referer',
            'referer': portalUrl,
            'expiration': 1209600,
            'f' : 'json'}

  token_response = encode(params,token_url)

  if "token" in token_response:
      token = token_response.get("token")
      return token

def encode (params, url,):
  data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
  data_encoded = data.encode("utf-8")
  request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data_encoded)
  context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,context= context)
  content = response.read()
  content_decoded = content.decode("utf-8")
  return json.loads(content_decoded)

def uploadFile(params, url):
  '''Creates a new item in a user's content.'''    
  return encode(params, url)

sourceToken = get_token(username='username' ,password='password')
pdfFile = open('C:\\some\\pdf\\path.pdf')


params={'fileName': 'E','multipart' :'true','f' :'pjson','token':sourceToken}
addItemUrl='some_portal_url/sharing/rest/content/users/username/addItem?multipart=true&'
reply = uploadFile(params,addItemUrl)
itemID = reply["id"]

#From here it doesn't work

parameters = {'file' : pdfFile,  'partNum': '1','token' : sourceToken,'f' : 'pjson'}
url = 'some_portal_url/sharing/rest/content/users/username/items/'+itemID+'/addpart'
r1 = uploadFile(parameters,url)

parameters = {'token' : sourceToken,'f' : 'json'}
url = 'some_portal_url/sharing/rest/content/users/username/items/'+itemID+'/commit'
r2 = uploadFile(parameters,url)
```

Comment: You tagged `arcrest` but dont show your imports. So its hard to say if you're actually using that package. For reference, you can check out Python just using builtin packages to do multipart upload within the `ago.py` sample here:  https://github.com/arcpy/sample-gp-tools/tree/master/SharePackage2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of trying, and unsuccesfully, to upload items to Portal using REST operations I found other option (stupid me, focusing in getting it to work with REST not looking other options):

```
import arcpy
from arcgis.gis import *

gis = GIS("here_your_portal_url",username="your_username", password="your_password")

data = "C:\\temp\\test.pdf" 

item_properties = {}
item_properties['type'] = "PDF"

fgdbdata = gis.content.add(item_properties, data, folder = "portal_folder_path")
```

And that is. I know this is not really the precise answer to my question, but is the workaround I got for it.

Cheers!

https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html